# Derivative of a section of a vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety and let $E \to X$ be a vector bundle over $X$, with sheaf of sections $\mathcal{E}$. If $s$ is a local section of $\mathcal{E}$, what is the derivative $ds$ exactly?

I guess the differential $d$ is a map $d \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to \Omega_X^1$ and the section $s$ can be viewed as a sheaf map $s \colon \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{E}$, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Is it possible that in your context you want to define $\bar{\partial} s$? Otherwise, you need extra structure (usually a connection) to form a coordinate-independent notion of a derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are asking is ill posed. In order to 'differentiate' a section of a vector bundle, you need a connection of the vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$. There are a few perspectives on this, but roughly a connection should give you something like $\mathcal{E}\rightarrow \mathcal{E} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega_X^1$. The de Rham differential is a connection of $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: Where exactly does Hartshorne discuss the morphism $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{E} \otimes \Omega_X^1$? It doesn't seem to be in II.8...

Comment: If you can stand reading french and old typesetting it is in these notes: [link](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number9.pdf).